# Do any commentators equate 2 אֲחִיָּהs?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, navi-prophets, samuel-shmuel-book-of, melachim-kings-book-of

In 1 Shmuel 14:3 a Kohen named אֲחִיָּה carries the ephod and is a descendant of Eli who lived in Shiloh. In 1 Melachim 11 there is a similarly named person who is a prophet and is also from Shiloh. Are there any sources who indicate that there two are the same person?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bava Batra 121b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.121b?lang=bi), [Achiya the Prophet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahijah_the_Shilonite) was alive in the time of Yaacov and lived an exceptionally long life:

> אֲחִיָּה הַשִּׁילוֹנִי רָאָה אֶת עַמְרָם אֵלִיָּהוּ רָאָה אֶת
> אֲחִיָּה
>
> Achiya the Shilonite saw Amram; Eliyahu saw Achiya the Shilonite

So it is the same Achiya from Melachim, who was a prophet (see [this Steinsalz for example](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.121b.6?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en)). Achiya from Shmuel, on the other hand was a priest, a descendant of Eli as you say, and therefore cannot be alive before Eli, who never saw Amram, so they are not the same.

To be sure, I've had a long look at many sources and can't find a single opinion that even tries to equate them, for whatever that is worth.